# Ice cube on a scale

Tags: experimental-physics, evaporation, humidity

Lets put an ice cube on a fairly precise scale and take readings over a period of several hours. The ice cube is situated in a saucer so that the water is retained after melting.

**What will the recorded curve look like?**

Suppose ambients conditions: 25°C, RH40% and 1013 mbar.

Comment: The mass is being measured?

Comment: @ParthVader Yes exactly. Lets assume mass reading every 2 mins or so. And also the ambient conditions are just average. Eg. 25°C RH40% and 1013 mbar.

Comment: maybe you should edit your question to say that the cup is completely sealed.

Comment: @Jody That would make the question much easier to answer but also less interesting ;)

Answer (score 4):

The way your question is phrased, it looks like you are expecting the mass to change. In that case the only change will be a slight mass loss due to evaporation, but the rate of evaporation is a variable - dependant on room temperature, air pressure humidity and how still the air is above the sample.

Comment: What about the influence of the temperature of the ice cube or the molten ice?

Comment: I'm totally going to start referring to water as molten ice now.

Comment: @MircBreitschuh, are you confusing change in density with change in mass?

Comment: I'm not. I wondered if the OP was. I am aware that the volume of the ice is greater than the than the water volume.

Comment: @Doresoom No, dont think so. I was just wondering what effect a cold surface could have in the context of humid air.

Answer (score 1):

The mass of the melted water will be **slightly lower** than the ice. This is because the **Latent Heat of Evaporation** is higher than the **Latent Heat of Fusion**, so more water will be evaporated as it is turns into the liquid form and hence more mass will be lost.

So gradually, as the water melts, the rate at which the mass is lost **increases** and hence the graph will be **decreasing** with the slope increasing slightly as time passes.

It is obvious that I am assuming all the other parameters in the environment like pressure, temperature and humidity to remain constant.

Comment: Are you sure that mass is evaporated while the ice cube is melting?

Comment: Pretty sure. Why do you ask?

Comment: Just thought that the low dew point of the water-ice mixture might play a role.

Comment: Dew point is for condensation, irrelevant here I think.

Comment: I meant of course the dew point of air-vapour mixture. Why do you think it is irrelevant?

Comment: There is no condensation here.

Comment: 'It is obvious that I am assuming all the other parameters in the environment like pressure, temperature and humidity to remain constant.' That is _not_ obvious. How could they (exactly), given your answer? :)

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat Yeah they will change, most obviously humidity. Bu we can assume the change to be negligible.

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat Yea, lets not confuse it too much and take the ambient conditions to be constant.

Answer (score 1):

The saucer ('cup') contains the ice at the beginning, which will melt so it contains water.

As we are interested in what the scale shows us - the change in mass - it is not important whether it's ice or not, the mass would not change.

The change we could observe is from evaporating water.
How quick the water evaporates depends on the surface area, the temperature. and the flow of air.

The surface area will decrease, as the ice melts - the surface becomes more flat, and smaller.
The average temperature of the surface will raise while the ice is melting. The water from molten ice will get warmer, while the surface of the ice stays at 0 degree C. As the surface of the ice gets smaller, contributing less to the average.

(*This part is referring to a cup with higher border used in an earlier version of the question. It was later replaced by a saucer with a very low border, see below for the effect of the change*:)

The evaporated water gets moved out of the cup as part of moist air moving out of it.
As long as the water is cold in relation to the environment, the air inside the cup will be cold, and thus of higher density, which causes only little water be moved out of the cup actually.

Related to that, there is the effect of the shape of the cup.
A higher cup causes slower evaporation by more keeping the moist, cold air from moving out.
A larger base area of the cup leads to a larger water/ice surface, causing faster evaporation.

To estimate the mass curve, all these effects need to be estimated, and - ignoring influences between them - added up in terms of evaporation per time.

(*Update assuming the cup is replaced by a saucer that has a very low border*:)

If we assume the border of the saucer is very low, just above the maximal water line (*) that would mean the evaporated water can leave the saucer pretty quickly.

It would cause a change in speed of evaporation during the time at the start, when the ice is still present. With a high cup, the wet ice surface would be covered by cold, moist air. With the low border, there is convection moving the cooling air down along the ice surface, where it can transport any water vapor avay easily.

[(*) The water line is maximal when the remaining ice starts to swim in the water. Before, it increases as the ice cube adds water by melting, after that, the level get's lower by evaporation.]

Comment: The influence of the cup. Good point! Let's assume the cup is more saucer like so that the melting cube is well accessible by ambient air.

Comment: Ok, it we assume the border of the cup is very low, just above the maximal water line (at the end of melting) that would mean the evaporated water can leave the "cup" pretty quickly. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: The change to a low cup would also make the whole experiment less dependent on how the surrounding air is moving or not. With the high cup, moving air could make a big difference in getting the cold moist air out of the cup. Now that's just irrelevant... But let's just assume some "constant air movement" and ignore that, right?

Comment: Yes I agree. There's only some undisturbed natural convection taking place at the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

If a cold beer can is taken out of the fridge on a warm day small water droplets form on its surface since the surface temperature is below the dew point of the moist ambient air. After a while, when the can reaches equilibrium temperature the water gets evaporated away again. 
For the ice cube the same is true in principle besides it evaporates away completely after some time.

In the actual experiment (with T=25°C and RH=50%) the maximum mass was reached after about 50 mins and the mass gain was quite significant (+1%).
[image]

Answer (score -2):

The matter is constant.  The mass increases (latent enthalpy of fusion plus specific heat as temperature rises) but ${m = E/c^2}$, hence way too small to measure.  What *is* big enough to measure is the deceasing net buoyancy for displaced air by the denser mass (lesser volume) of  of water versus ice, about 1.3 ${mg/cm^3}$ differential air volume at STP.  If the cup is sealed that dos not obtain.

Comment: Have you thought of evaporation?

Comment: If it is below the dew point, condensation.  These are irrelevant footnotes.  Air displacement is real in extreme accuracy measurements.  Is there anybody here who can stand at a bench and not embarrass themselves?

Comment: Take an icecube. Put it on a scale. Put the scale in the desert. Go next day, there is no ice cube. Scale measures $0 \mathrm{kg}$. OP asks how fast will mass decrease. Are you sure you're answering the same question?

Comment: @UncleAl Buoyancy! That's an intersting aspect. But why you think condensation/evaporation is not relevant?

Comment: You control condensation or evaporation, for they are external variables.  Sample air buoyancy is real not constructed hokum.  As I wrote, does anybody here know how do to lab work?

Comment: @UncleAl The ice cube is in open contact with the atmosphere. How you want to control mass transfer?

Comment: Are you trying to say that water doesn't evaporate? This is know by kids... If you want a proof, spit on the table, after some time it will disappear.

Comment: @jinawee I believe UncleAl has in mind _really_ accurate measurements, where those things are controled by keeping it in tight enclosure. For our purpose $0.1mg$ readings will do.

Comment: @MircBreitschuh But that is not the experiment you proposed. And $E=mc^2$ makes no sense here.